# Is it possible to post data to couch db and return data?

Tags: post, couchdb

For example I would like to send the users score to the database and instead of it returning the typical status, id and rev I would like it to return the users rank. I'm guessing this isn't possible but figured I would ask.

Answer (score 1):

The response to an HTTP POST/PUT should really only be used to help you confirm that it succeeded.

I'm even struggling to see even how you can get the rank of a user returned by a couchdb view, unless you retrieve the data for all users and work out the position of your user.

This use case ...

- Simple structured data clearly tabular
- The requirement to respond fast to a numerical column (Method to calculate the rank for a score)
- OR the requirement to trigger an update a score table each time a rank is submitted.

... very much smells like a classical case where you may want to use a relational DB.

Comment: I'm currently fetching the users rank using a view that counts the number of records with a lower score then the users current score. I swtiched from mysql to couchdb because the sheer number of read/writes on the mysql db was crippling my server no matter how much I scaled the server up. A majority of my queires are reads and from all the research I've done the reads should be quite a bit quicker then mysql but the writes are actually slower. I was going to release it into a live scenario to test it out and see which one performance wise is better for my needs.

Comment: If you need a single record that you have by Id, then couchdb is likely quicker than MySQL if you use a `WHERE` clause that is not backed up with a good index or if the index needs constant rewriting. If you don't need the absolutely most recent data in MySQL you could add new scores to a staging table (no index etc.) and pull all results into an indexed table on a schedule that triggers this every few minutes to every few hours. Then provide the results based on a query to that indexed table.

Comment: I'd say 90% of the calls are reads to a single user where I will know the id. 8% are updates to a user where I will know the id and the rest is a list of the top 50 users sorted by score.

Comment: So if write performance on an indexed relational table is an issue, then you could just do the writes (I assume scores) to an entirely unindexed table and once every few minutes add them into a table where the best score by user is stored, with an index on the score. It seems that the user data does not need much indexing either so the updates here should be cheap. Finally if you want the scores to include the latest game score of your player, then you just store this in your client app and add it to the top 50 scores in the client.

Answer (score 0):

**If the result can be calculated from the document you are to change with your http request, then you can use an update handler to `PUT` a change to the document and `return` that result:**

```
// 'myhandler' update function
function(doc, req) {
  // create a shorthand for json reponses
  var json_reponse = function(obj, code) {
    return { 
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      , body: JSON.stringify(obj) 
      , code: code
      }
  }

  // assume the incoming body is json and parse it
  // needs proper error handling still
  var body = JSON.parse(req.body)

  // doc is the user document we are patching
  // return an error if it isn't there
  if(!doc) 
    return [null, json_response({error: 'user document not found'}, 404)]

  // return an error if new_score is missing from body
  if(!body.new_score) 
    return [null, json_response({error: 'missing property new_score'}, 400)

  // now patch the user doc
  doc.score = body.new_score

  // calculate the new rank depending on your own method
  var my_rank = my_rank_function(doc.score, Math.PI, 'bananarama')

  return [doc, json_response({success: true, rank: my_rank}, 200)
}
```

Now `PUT` new data to receive the new rank:

```
request(
  { method: 'PUT'
  , url: httptp://127.0.0.1:5984/mydb/_design/myddoc/_update/myhandler/myuserdocid
  , json: {"new_score": 42}
  , headers: { "Content-Type: application/json" }
  }
, function(err, response, body) {
    console.log("user's new rank:", JSON.parse(body).rank)
  }
)
```

should print `user's new rank: LEVEL 11 EIGHTIES GIRL GROUP LEADER`

nb: I'm not at work so cannot confirm the code works, but you should get the hang of it...